# On an EventEmitter, how can I know all the events I can listen to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, eventemitter

Supposing I have an object that inherited from `EventEmitter`, like a stream or any other, is there a good way to know all the events I can listen to, and all the attached event listeners ?

I think the second part of the question is easy, [`emitter.listeners(event)`](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_listeners_event) will tell me all the listeners to an event. But is there a way to know beforehand all the events I can listen to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no public API or documentation to help you list all the events an EventEmitter can emit.

But if you look in the [EventEmitter source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L132-L150), you can see that all events are stored in the `_events` property, so your code can loop on the keys of the object and find all possible events. Here is an exemple on how to list the event names:

```
var ee = new SomeEventEmitter();
console.log(Object.keys(ee._events));
```

However, as this is undocumented, I'd suggest you to be careful with this.

*Edit:* Some modules provide a list of possible events, see for instance [SAX](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js#events) (and the [corresponding source](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/master/lib/sax.js#L26-L44)).

Comment: This only lists the events that have at least one active listener. If nothing registered a listener yet, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful when diagnosing MaxListenersExceededWarning:

[Emitter Event Names](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#emittereventnames)

I used it like this:

```
const ee = new EventEmitter();
console.log(`Event Names: ${ee.eventNames()}`);
```